# UITableViewController inheriting from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, uikit

In order to fix bug I need to change a `UIViewController` into a `UITableViewController`. Only thing is that the current viewController is a subclass of a base `UIViewController`. How can I inherit behavior from `base`? Creating a whole other `BaseTableViewController` sounds very redundant.

Comment: just change super Class name `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController` but in storyboard you have to take new `UITableViewController`, `UIViewController` will not work.

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad Unfortunately can't do that. There are other classes that use this `BaseViewController`, and changing that to `UITableViewController` breaks app and crashes at runtime.